# How to write function in Emacs Lisp for syntax highlighting?

Tags: regex, haskell, emacs, syntax-highlighting

I need to add Haskell syntax highlighting for Emacs. I can't create a regexp for functions definitions highlighting, because Emacs Lisp regexps don't support looking forward(?=) and looking backward(?<=). In the [Elisp manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Search_002dbased-Fontification.html#Search_002dbased-Fontification) I read that 
searching keywords can be realized by function. This function must not return `nil` and must set `match-beginning` and `match-end`.

I created a function that finds Haskell functions definitions, but the syntax highlighting doesn't work.

```
(defun get-cur-character (pos)
  (aref (buffer-substring (1- pos) pos) 0))

(defun find-equal-character (pos)
  (let ((curchar ?0)
        (result nil)
        (max-pos (point-max)))
      (while (and (not (equal curchar ?\n)) (< pos max-pos))
          (setq curchar (get-cur-character pos))
          (setq pos (1+ pos))
          (if (equal curchar ?=)
              (progn
                  (setq result t)
                  (setq curchar ?\n))))
    result))

(defun highlight-haskell-function (limit)
    (save-excursion
        (if (not (null (re-search-forward "^\\([a-z]+\\w*\\)" limit t)))
            (find-equal-character (match-end 0))
            (nil))))

(provide 'haskell-mode)
(font-lock-add-keywords 'haskell-mode '((highlight-haskell-function . 'font-lock-keyword-face)))
```

Functions description:

- `get-cur-character` - return character by position.
- `find-equal-character` - find character = from pos to nearest `\n` character and return t or nil.
- `highlight-haskell-function` - find words, that begin with lowercase letter, then call find-equal-character with position of searched word and return t or nil.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work" here? Does any highlighting occur at all? Does it crash with an error? What do you expect to happen?

Comment: You seem to be returning `(nil)` from `highlight-haskell-function`, rather than `nil`. That gives me a `Symbol's function definition is void` error.

Comment: Doesn't `haskell-mode` do proper highlighting?

Comment: AJFarmar, when I run haskell-mode nothing changes, emacs continue normal working. I expect that functions definitions like someFunc = undefined change color.